# Making X amount of HTTP requests with a batch?

Tags: apex, batch

I would like to know what the optimal way of doing this in Salesforce is.

Imagine the following scenario, I need to have batch as I need to make over 100 HTTP calls, The HTTP request would be sent to a URL that looks similar to this, 
www.google/page=1, then it would make another request to www.google/page=2 and so on, at some point we would reach the limit of 100 HTTP requests so we would need to implement a batch, this number keeps growing day by day, instead of creating an object which would hold the page number, what would be the best way to achieve this same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that page number incremental? successive no drops in between?

Comment: How are you deciding which page number needs to be called?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Yes, the number is incremental, always starts at 1 and ends at X.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with a similar requirement, I used a Queueable instead of a batch.  Effectively, it would check before performing a callout whether it still had callouts left, and if it did not it would stop and requeue itself with the same internal state, so that the next run could start where the last left off.

In your case, if there isn't an Object to iterate over, this would seem to be the best option.  It also avoids the issue that a batch with a callout per record basically can't have a scope over 100 at most, but there's no way to enforce that from the class.

Comment: You can iterate over List<Integer> or any list in Batch. Use of sObject is optional.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Fair point, though the point still stands for any Object I think.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, wouldn't a List<Integer> cause a HTTP callout error? I cannot remember, but I think at some point I attempted it and ran into callout limitation. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last number in some custom setting/ custom metadata or label. Fetch it in the start method and create a list of Integer for it. And just get it going by creating `List<Integer>`.

```
global class MyBatchClass implements  Database.Batchable<Integer>{


    global List<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){


        Integer count ;//Fetch it from Custom setting
        List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
        for(Integer i =1 ; i<= count ; i++){
            intList.add(i);
        }

        return intList;

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Integer> scope){

        for(Integer i : scope){
            //DO callout
            String calloutURL = 'https://www.google.com/page='+i;
            //
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

As we can do at max 100 callouts , exceute your batch like

```
Database.executeBathc(new MyBatchClass(),100 );
```

As batch runs in chunks of 100, you should be good to go.